# Oracle Database Migration - Triggers Related

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, data-migration

We had been migrating a data dump from one db instance to another(both being oracle 11gR2). We experience that triggers in the destination db instance tables are either invalid or not migrated and we had to recreate them.
Could anyone please explain if this is a valid scenario?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid is very different to "not migrated".

If an invalid trigger has valid syntax then it will be automatically recompiled on the next triggering event: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm

If the trigger is not present then you'd have to investigate your unloading and loading methodologies. Are you using data pump?

Comment: I now understand difference between invalid and not migrated. There could be an issue in data dump. Let me update once this is over with.